# Real time object detection

Tags: python, object, argparse, detection, yolo

I have tried this code, this is yolo object detection code:

```
# USAGE
# python real_time_object_detection.py --prototxt MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt.txt --model MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel

# import the necessary packages
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.2,
    help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
    
The error is as follows:

usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -p PROTOTXT -m MODEL [-c CONFIDENCE]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -p/--prototxt, -m/--model
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

I have not tried this code before this is the first time i have used it copied it from a website piimagesearch. i am not able to run this code also dont know "argparse" as well. if someone would explain it would be much helpful. this is not the complete code

Comment: What is unclear your the error message?

Comment: @KlausD. I dont even know that. I think it is something to do with argparse

Comment: If has something to do with how you have to call the program and what arguments are missing.

Comment: you have to run this script in console/terminal with arguments  `ipykernel_launcher.py -p PROTOTXT -m MODEL` - and put correct values in place of `PROTOTXT` and `MODEL`. You can't run it using only `ipykernel_launcher.py` or clicking on script in window.

Comment: Does that top `usage` line make any sense to you?